# Compiling pure C and C++

Tags: c++, c

Can i compile next code ?

main.CPP   c++ languge file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file.h"
int main()
{
    printf("Hello");
    printf(func());
    return 0;
}
```

file.C    c languge file

```
#include "file.h"

char* func()
{
    return "This is a C string";
}
```

file.H

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

char* func();

#endif // FILE_H
```

Comment: Yes you can? What are you really having trouble with?

Comment: try it...why you are asking to us

Comment: I believe that "pure" C++ would need to `#include <cstdio>` instead.

Comment: What is "pure C++" ? Is `printf` in there? Or as @Ludin points out ... `#include <stdio.h>` or `#include<cstdio>` in "pure c++" code can be considered quite an oxymoron.

Answer (score 15):

No, not as written. The linking will fail to find the `func()` function, which will typically be "mangled" which will be your clue.

You need to tell the C++ compiler that the `file.h` file declares a C function, by using:

```
extern "C" {
#include "file.h"
}
```

This is because C++ does name-mangling which isn't used in C. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Handling_of_C_symbols_when_linking_from_C.2B.2B).

As minor points:

- The C function should be `const char * func(void);`. Empty parenthesis don't mean the same thing in C as in C++.
- The C++ should use `cout <<`, not `printf()`.
- Even if using `printf()`, don't use externally-sourced text as the first argument, it can be dangerous. Less so when the "external" is still your own source file of course, but it's better to write `printf("%s\n", func());` and be safe.

Comment: What error the compiler will throw?

Comment: Great thx))) Compiler throws undefined reference to `func()' without extern